# Spring - conditionally disable EntityListener

Tags: java, spring, jpa, configuration

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners({MyListener.class})
public class MyEntityClass {
...
}
```

```
@Service
public class MyListener {
   @PostUpdate
   public void myPostUpdate() {
   ...
   }
}
```

I would like to conditionally (the best would by based on `application.properties` property) disable EntityListener. **Is it possible to achieve?**

Comment: You can't disable the EntityListener, but you can inject a property into your listener and carry out the listener logic conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve this is by using a `@Value` and test if post-update should be executed.

```java
@Service
class MyListener {

    @Value("${my-listener-update:false}")
    boolean update;

    @PostUpdate
    void updated(Object entity){
        if(update) { // check if post update should be used
            System.out.println("updated " + entity);
        }
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
my-listener-update = true
```

Best to provide a default value, in the example it's set to `false`